# Converting GraphQL mutation to Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, graphql

I am looking to convert this specific GraphQL code snippet to GAS.

```html
mutation {
  createReportExport(input: {
    reportId: "XXXX",
    fileContentType: CSV,
    frequency: ONCE,
    reportFilters: [
      {
        attributeName: "Sale Date",
        relativeDateQuery: {
          greaterEqual: "P14D"
        }
      }
    ]
  }) {
    reportExport {
      id
      fileUrl
    }
  }
}
```

Below is what I have tried in GAS

```html
  var query = 'mutation {createReportExport(input: {reportId: "urn:abc:Report:3318979a-7628-44ab-aa0d-a822f856b908",fileContentType: CSV,frequency: ONCE,reportFilters: [{attributeName: "Sale Date",relativeDateQuery: {greaterEqual: "P10D"}}]}) {reportExport {idfileUrl}}}'
  
 var query2 = {
  'operationName': 'Mutation',
  'query': {query},
  'variables': {}
  }

  var ql = '{insert URL}';
  var content = {
    "method": 'POST', 
    "headers": {"Authorization": httpBasicHeader,
    "contentType": "application/json"},
    "payload": JSON.stringify(query2)
    };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(ql, content);
  var data = (response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(data);
```

I have two variables, 'query' and 'query2' that I have tried. I am getting a {"errors":[{"message":"No query document supplied"}]} error message when running it in GAS.

When I run the first code snippet in another environment, it runs successfully. I am looking to keep my project within GAS if possible, since I have figured out the rest of the problems with my project and this is the last thing holding me back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the `query` property in `query2` should not be wrapped in an object:

```js
var query2 = {
  'operationName': 'Mutation',
  // no { } here:
  'query': query,
  'variables': {}
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Nils Hartmann ! I tried the above adjustment and it is still producing the same error message. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if the http header should be called `Content-Type` instead of `contentType`. Also you specify an `operationName` but have no such operation in your query, maybe that causes the error. I think it's safe to remove `operationName` (and `variables`) from `query2`

Comment: Thanks for that, those two changes allowed me to produce the query within the log. I am still fairly new to GraphQL/JS/GAS, is there a way to just grab the values produced with "fileUrl"? I want to use it for another part of my script

Comment: I'm not a GAS export, but I think that getContentText should include your graphql response in JSON format, so `var graphqlResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())` should give you a JSON object, with a `data` node and there you find the response of your mutation (`{data: reportExport: { id: "...", fileUrl: "..." } }`)